# How to get position of the element of arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Imagine that i have a list with a ArrayAdapter like this:

[image]

When I long pressed Ubuntu I will go to the **Context Menu**

[image]

Well, my question is how I can get the position in arrayadapter of Ubuntu, when I long pressed and I go to the context menu?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Creating Menus Dev Guide section Creating a Context Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu).

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
   AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
   // ...
}
```

[AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.html)

Comment: I checked already, and i got the methods that i need like `public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, but i dont know how to get the position of the elements in my list (adapter).

Comment: Updated with how to get AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the item, you can get the position using `getPosition(T Item)` which is detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getPosition%28T%29) and is invoked from an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: what does T type mean?

Comment: @Wang'lPakhrin T is usually used to denote a generic type. In this case, it's whatever the type of the ArrayAdapter is.